# CenOS 7 - Javascript Files don't update

Tags: linux, apache-httpd, cache, javascript

I have a small issue on my server. 
Javascript `*.js` files in a certain folder don't update.
I mean, files update but in the browser, I see the old version.
I have installed a new browser on my computer but I still see the old version of the file.
If I open the file via vi or FileZilla I see the new version.

What can cause this?
How can I Disable server cache?

/***Update***/

If I create a new file I see the file content but if I update the content of the file, I don't see the updated data and still see the old version.

If I change the content of the file and I move it to another folder I will see the new data.

If I take the file with the new content and put it back where it initially was I see the old file content in the browser.

The server I have I  Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS).

I don't have a caching layer between the server and the data.

I add this screenshot of the folder and the files.
maybe it helps...
[image]

Comment: Need more information. What server are you running? Apache, nginx? Is there any kind of caching layer (Akamai, varnish) between the server and your browser? It's not possible to give you any answer with the information you provided.

Comment: I have updated the question, I don't use a caching layer.
The weird thing is that this happens only in this specific folder. 
I have managed to update the files by restarting the apache. 
When I restarted again further changes haven't been updated.

Comment: Need to look in the apache config files for caching static js files. Look in `/etc/httpd.conf` and the files in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/*`. There is likely some setting which is caching the js files. This page may also help https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/caching.html

Comment: I dont see something wrong... 
Everything is pretty out fo the box.
I have installed the server, added amp (apache, mysql and php) 
I added the domain using a conf file in the  `/etc/httpd/conf.d` folder and that's it

Comment: Is there something more I can check?

Answer (score 1):

At the end, the cache was kept by Cloudflare...
I purged the host cache and saw all the changes.